# Frequency of Some Value for Each Column Sub-Heading

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns, one with people and times associated with those people, and one filled with 0s and 1s.  For any given person there is some associated combination of 0s and 1s.  We can determine the frequency with which 1s occur by taking the ratio of 1s to 0s for each individual and then placing this information beside the correct 'person header' to which the frequency information belongs.  The data looks something like this:

[image]

How might one go about making a formula to do this sort of thing?

Comment: @pnuts I am but it would require a method for splitting.  The data was simply copied from a pivot table and there area large number of entries so individually splitting the column up would be tough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number next to "John" is supposed to be your formula result, and that cell is B2, use this formula:

```
=SUM(B3:INDEX(B3:B$1000,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A3:A$1000),),0)-1))
```

If your data goes beyond row 1000, adjust the 1000s to be the last row number of your data. Then copy the formula and paste it in for the other name cells (next to "Tim" and "Samantha" in your example)

Comment: I realize I wasn't clear with my example - I should have included the desired column.  Essentially the desired output would be a third column with values beside John, Tim, Samantha, and so on, the value being the ratio of 0s to 1s.